# Thymeleaf: Check if list contains a string containing a substring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a combined check that needs to happen in Thymeleaf:

- List contains an item - can be done as `th:if="${#lists.contains(data, '...')}"` if you know the exact string
- Item contains a substring - **When iterating**, can be done as `th:each="item : *{data}" th:if="${#strings.contains(item,'(')}"` e.g. to check for the substring "(" among the items of the list

I need to display a UL tag **if the list contains an item containing the substring "("**. No iteration, just this combined condition. How do I achieve that in one line?

```
<ul th:if="..."> <!-- This must be a combined check, no iteration. I don't even want to output the UL if not satisfied -->
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this with [collection selection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions-collection-selection).  Just test if the list size is greater than zero.  Something like this will work:

```
<ul th:if="${#lists.size(data.?[#strings.contains(#this,'(')]) GT 0}">

</ul>
```

Comment: What goes in the `contains(data, '...')`? I don't have an exact string I'm looking for!

Comment: You're the one that put it there, lol... I guess you don't need it?  You just want the second part? (See the edited answer.)

Comment: Yes, this works, thank you. I guess Collection Selection is like Java Stream/Lambdas?

Comment: Yes, you can use collection selection (and the related collection projection) to do operations on lists like a stream/lambda.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have a list like this, for testing:

```java
List<String> data = Stream.of("abc", "d(ef", "ghi")
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can use the following:

```html
<ul th:if="${#strings.contains( #strings.listJoin(data,'') ,'(')}">
    bazinga
</ul>
```

This first concatenates each item in the list into a single string.

It then checks to see if that string contains any `(` characters.

Comment: Yes, this also works, thanks. I guess the other Collection Selection answer offered here is even more appropriate, but the ListJoin (into a single string) also works great as a workaround.

Comment: Agreed - collection selection is great for this. If you don't use Spring and SpEL, then this approach would still work, using the standard Thymeleaf dialect. But you do have Spring, in your case.